# 32-bit cluster.exe on 64 bit Windows 2008

Tags: windows, cluster-computing, wow64

We have an installation program that runs in Perl 32-bit. This program needs to get information on cluster resources, so it runs cluster.exe (using backticks) and parse its output.

On Windows Server 2003 this went well, as a 32-bit version of cluster.exe existed under syswow64. However, such a 32-bit version does not exist on Windows Server 2008, so the backticks run of cluster.exe says it can't find such an executable, as 32-bit process look for it under syswow64.

Can someone think of a way we can bypass this problem and get the cluster resource information?
One manual way is to copy the 64-bit version of cmd.exe from system32, and then run it with "/c cluster.exe" which will start the 64-bit cluster.exe under system32. (Copying the cluster.exe won't work well, as it can't find the cluster cache.) However, this is only good as a manual workaround, and not as a solution to all users.

Is there another way to cause windows to start the 64-bit cluster.exe?

Thanks,
splintor

PS
A similar question was [asked on technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverClustering/thread/f444dc91-e421-4dcf-b82f-7b271ce31559) a month ago, but didn't get a real answer.

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: Hi Richard, I didn't get your comment. Can you explain, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two possible solutions:
One is to write a small 64-bit application named cluster.exe that simply calls %SystemRoot%\System32\cluster.exe (using system()), and put it under %SystemRoot%\syswow64. Since it is a 64-bit application, the correct 64-bit cluster.exe application will be called.

Another solution is to use the sysnative redirection (as explained [here](http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/how-to-suppress-and-bypass-system32-file-system-redirect-to-syswow64-folder-with-sysnative/)), so now we check - if %SystemRoot%\**System32**\cluster.exe exists, we use it, else if %SystemRoot%\**Sysnative**\cluster.exe exists we use it, else we use plain cluster.exe.

Note: this is very similar to [this telnet.exe problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710938/process-starttelnet-exe-throws-exception) that just got answered.